# Must two separable states that are $\epsilon$-close in trace distance admit close separable decompositions?

Tags: entanglement

$\newcommand{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}$ Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers. Does there exist a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$, and whenever two separable density operators $\rho, \sigma \in SepD(\complex^n \otimes \complex^m)$ satisfy $||{\rho-\sigma}||_1<\epsilon$, there exist separable decompositions $\rho=\sum_{i=1}^k v_iv_i^* \otimes u_iu_i^*$, $\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^k w_iw_i^* \otimes z_iz_i^*$, where possibly some of the $v_i, u_i, w_i,z_i$ are zero, for which
$$f(\epsilon) \geq \max\{ ||v_iv_i^* \otimes u_iu_i^*-w_iw_i^* \otimes z_iz_i^*|| : i \in [k]\}?$$
In other words, if two separable states are close, must they admit separable decompositions which are also close?

Comment: The way of expressing this with a continuous functions sounds a bit odd; isn't this equivalent to the canonical "$\forall \epsilon\,\exists\delta$?

Comment: In the end one can ask the same question for convex sets. It seems quite clear the answer is "yes", though a direct proof seems to require some special attention for cases which are at the boundary. I'd suspect this is a known result in convex sets.